# Laravel 8: Access Model property in relation method

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have an `Activity` Model with a `resource` relation that needs to check properties of the `Activity` prior to returning a relationship type. I'm doing this in order to have a "dynamic" relationship between different types of models.

```
class Activity extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [/*....a bunch of fields....*/];
    protected $with = ['user', 'company', 'resource'];

    public function company(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    public function user(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'generated_by');
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function resource(): HasOne {
        if ($this->type === '1') {
            return $this->hasOne(Document::class, 'id', 'document_id');
        } else if ($this->type === '2') {
            return $this->hasOne(Workflow::class, 'id', 'workflow_id');
        } else {
            throw new \Exception("err");
        }
    }

}
```

I load activities as follows within a controller (will change this to a service class later):

```
$activities = $request->user()->company->activities;
```

I thought that this would be OK, but debugging it I can see that in the `resource()` relationship method, `$this` does not have data loaded, including the `$attributes` associative array which would typically contain the properties loaded from the database:

[image]

Removing `'resource'` from the `$with` array and adding the following loop within the controller causes everything to work as expected (the `resource` relation returns the correct data, meaning that `$this` must have been loaded with data)

```
$activities = $request->user()->company->activities;
foreach ($activities as $event) {
    $event->resource; // IDE says result is not used anywhere but there must be some kind of side effect?
    // $event->resource()->get(); does not work as `resource` doesn't get added as a property to the model
}
```

Questions:

Is there a way to guarantee that model properties will be loaded by the time relationship methods run so that I can access `$this->type` in the `resource()` method without receiving `null`? or am I just misusing something/setting up a dynamic relationship in a bad way?

Comment: relationships methods are not meant to be dynamic in this way ... often the relationship is loaded from a new nonexisting model instance, such as for eager loading, which means that instance (that the relationship method is called on to get the relationship object from) doesn't have attributes as it isn't representing any record ... we have polymorphic relationships for dynamic relationships (though you would have to adjust your schema)

Comment: I see, thanks for the information. I will adjust my database schema. If you would like to turn your comment into an answer I am happy to upvote and accept it.